# jquery $.post multiple values not working?

Tags: php, jquery

On test_process.js, when I use just one name value i.e. 'name' on it's own then the code works with no problem. As soon as I use a second value, adding 'yes' then the code doesn't work at all and nothing is echoed. I know this must be a small fix?

[image: Screenshot]

The error is 'uncaught type error: undefined is not a function'

test_process.js

```
$('#insert_submit').on('click', function(event) {
    alert("Hello");
    event.preventDefault();
    var insert_template = $('#insert_template');
    var insert_name = $('#insert_template_name').val();
    $.post('ajax/name.php', {name: insert_template.val(), yes: insert_name.val()}, function(data) {
        $('div#insert_data').text(data);
   });      
});
```

name.php

```
<?php
include('C:\xampp\htdocs\email1\class\db.php');
require_once('C:\xampp\htdocs\email1\config\db.php');
require_once('C:\xampp\htdocs\email1\class\Login.php');

    $login = new Login();
    $user = $_SESSION['user_name'];
    $db = new Database();
    $db->connect();

 //test
 echo $_POST['name'];
 echo $_POST['yes'];
```

Comment: Put your data in a variable bevor submitting it via post and do a console.log() to view if your data is correct.

Comment: The posted answer gets it. However there are quite a few things with this code that could be improved. Once you are satisfied with the answer you should consider heading over to [the code review stackexchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) and getting some comments on that front.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've called `.val` twice.

First here:

```
var insert_name = $('#insert_template_name').val();
// -----------------------------------------^^^^^^
```

then here

```
$.post('ajax/name.php', {name: insert_template.val(), yes: insert_name.val()}
// -------------------------------------------------------------------^^^^^^
```

You only need (and want) one of those.